# Converting Timing to TimeObject

Tags: function-construction, timing

What's the proper way to get `Timing` and post-process it for example to convert to a `TimeObject` as a defined function?

In line, this replacement works as intended:

```
Inverse[Table[RandomReal[], {3000}, {3000}]]; // Timing // 
 Replace[{timeSec_, value_} :> {TimeObject[{0, 0, timeSec}], value}]
```

gives (full form):

```
List[TimeObject[List[0,0,3.450302`],"Instant",None],Null]
```

but when trying to define a function to perform both the timing and conversion, the actual timing extracted is not that of the intended input expression:

```
unitTiming[expr_] := Timing[expr] // Replace[{timeSec_,value_}:> {TimeObject[{0,0,timeSec}],value}]
```

Testing on the matrix inversion above:

```
Inverse[Table[RandomReal[], {3000}, {3000}]]; // unitTiming
```

gives:

```
List[TimeObject[List[0,0,0.000011`],"Instant",None],Null]
```

I've tried several variations on the definition (eg using `RightComposition`) but can't get the desired results.

Comment: Doesn't `TimeObject` refer to an instant in time? It doesn't seem to make sense to convert a duration to a `TimeObject`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, that's a good point, b/c it zeros after 24hours, but for the my purposes it's more convenient than using say` UnitConvert[Quantity[timeSec,"Seconds"],"Minutes"]` because `TimeObject` auto-converts to minutes if > 60sec (ditto hours), whereas I'd have to manually tune the logic. In any case, using `Quantity` has the same problem.

Comment: Try `SetAttributes[unitTiming, HoldAll]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, that works, thanks. Can you explain why holding works in this case? One would expect `Timing[expr]` to already be evaluated on the input, prior to the `Replace`?

Comment: @Szabolcs, this is really a separate question but is it possible to obtain both `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` for the same input?

Comment: Without that, `expr` evaluates *before* the definition of `unitTiming` kicks in. With the HoldAll, the unevaluated `expr` gets literally substituted into the RHS of `unitTiming`'s definition.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming[Timing[expr]]`

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses Szabolcs' points in comments, including avoiding `TimeObject`

```
(* returns S, MS, HMS depending on the magnitude of the input *)
minimalTimeQuantity[time_] := Replace[time, {
    t_ /; (t < 60) :> Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{t}], MixedUnit[{"Seconds"}]],
    t_ /; (t < 3600) :> 
     Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{0, t}], MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]],
    t_ :> Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{0, 0, t}], 
      MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]]}
   ];
```

Then package output for both types of timing:

```
(* data structure to return both timing and absolute timing *)
timingsAssociation[t_, absT_] := <|"Timing" -> minimalTimeQuantity[t], 
  "Absolute Timing" -> minimalTimeQuantity[absT]|>
```

Finally, the actual timing function returning quantities:

```
timings[expr_] := 
 AbsoluteTiming[Timing[expr]] // 
  Replace[{{absT_, {t_, Null}} :> 
     timingsAssociation[t, 
      absT], {absT_, {t_, value_}} :> {timingsAssociation[t, absT], value}}]
SetAttributes[timings, HoldAll]
```

Test:

```
Inverse[Table[RandomReal[], {1000}, {1000}]]; // timings
```

gives:

[image]